# Wordpress - Pulling in dynamic category images to a li

Tags: php, wordpress, image, html-lists, categories

I'm running into a problem pulling in category images in dynamically to a li. Im kinda new to Wordpress and have no issues building the theme but sometimes run into issues pulling in the content I need. Heres what i'm looking to do.

I have a section on this site(http://www.moderateindividual.com.php53-13.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/) "News Topics". Each icon (image box) will be a category and the image will be associated with the category. Im going to use ACF to attach the image to the category but I need to be able to pull those images into the li dynamically and each time a new category and image is added in the back end, it needs to just automatically load on this list. I also need to be able to EXCLUDE some categories that don't belong on their. For instance the homepage hero slideshow is loaded via a category, so I would need to leave that category off the list. When that image is clicked it also needs to load the category title and description in the blue box below.

So this is my problem i'm trying to solve. If anyone could steer me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks
-Dan

Comment: Am I right in thinking the topics / categories are on this page : http://www.moderateindividual.com.php53-13.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/news/ ?

Comment: I'd take a look at this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories particularly looking at the exclude part - For excluding categories (I'd also exclude by ID)

I'd then loop through each categories and set a class on your li dependant on the category name. i.e <li class="character"><a href="#">Character</a></li>

Comment: Thanks for that link, that will help a lot for this. But this way I will still run into the issue of every time I added a new category and image, I will need to go into the code and add a new <li> for my new category, I was really hoping that when I added in the backend of Wordpress it would just pull it in to that <li>. Know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, know what you mean. You could set a default image. i.e if the class doesn't exist. Still put an image in. But other than that, Not too sure whether you can do what you're planning

Comment: yea, thats actually not a bad idea for a backup plan. Thanks for your input on this. Very much appreciated!

Comment: No worries, good luck! I'd also maybe look to restricting the user to a certain amount of categories, which would prevent your issue of differing classes.